# Assembly - Inc instruction increase by value in ax

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm writing a simple assembly code here, enter an array of number and print it to the screen. Here's my code

```
INCLUDE LIB1.ASM
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.DATA 
    msg1 db 13,10,'Enter array length: $'
        msg2 db 13,10,'a[$'
    msg3 db "]=$"
        msg4 db 13,10,"Your array is: $"
    msg5 db 13,10,"Do you want to continue? (y/n): $"
    space db " $"
    n dw ?
    a dw ?
    i dw ?
.CODE
    Main:
        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        CLRSCR

        HienString msg1         ;proc to show string
        call VAO_SO_N           ; proc to enter a number and save in ax
        mov n,AX        ;save array length to n
        mov cx, ax      ; give cx array length to loop
        lea bx,a        ; bx point to first element of a
        mov i,0         ;

    ;Loop to enter numbers
    L1:
        PrintString msg2    ;print string a[
        mov ax,i        ;move i into ax to show
        call PRINT_NUM_N     ;proc to print a number in ax
        PrintString msg3         ;print string ]=
        call ENTER_NUM_N    ;enter array elements, result in ax
        mov [BX],ax     ;move numer into array
        inc i           ; increase i by 1
        add bx,2        ; bx point to next element
        loop L1         
        mov cx,n        ; move n into cx 
        lea bx,a        ; bx point to first element of a
        
    PrintString msg4    ; "Your array is: "
    ;Loop to show array 
    L2: 
        mov AX,[BX]         ;move array number into ax
        call    PRINT_NUM_N         ; print number in ax
        HienString  space   ; " "   
        add BX,2            ; next element
        loop L2

    PrintString msg5          ;""Do you want to continue? (y/n):"
    mov  ah,1       
        int     21h                ; Get a character from keyboard
        cmp  al,'y'     ;if its y, jump to exit, jump to Main otherwise
        jne    Exit     
        jmp   Main      
    Exit:
        mov  ah,4ch     
        int     21h

        INCLUDE LIB2.ASM
    end Main
```

When i run that code, i got this

```
Enter array length: 5
a[0]=1 
a[1]=3
a[4]-5
a[5]=6
a[6]=7
Your array is: 1 7 5 6 7
Do you want to continue? (y/n):
```

When I ran debug, the variable i was added to the value of the array stored in ax instead of adding 1. What happened and how do I fix it

Comment: `a dw ?` only reserves space for one `word`.  If you treat it as an array, the second element overlaps with `i`.  Don't do that.  Reserve more space for your array, like `a dw 16 dup(?)`